# Pycharm 4.5.3 debugger crashes when importing matplotlib.pyplot on Windows

Tags: python, debugging, matplotlib, ipython, pycharm

If I hit a breakpoint after the pyplot import the debugger just exists with:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

I figure this is a clue: If I drop a breakpoint on the pyplot import and import pyplot manually (in the debugger console) I get the below message.  This doesn't happen in pycharm 3.5.3.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3066, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-1-eff513f636fd>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.3\helpers\pydev\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 109, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.3\helpers\pydev\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt4agg.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QTAgg
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.3\helpers\pydev\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .backend_qt5 import QtCore
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.3\helpers\pydev\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .qt_compat import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, _getSaveFileName, __version__
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.3\helpers\pydev\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt_compat.py", line 91, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.3\helpers\pydev\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.3\helpers\pydev\pydev_ipython\qt_loaders.py", line 45, in load_module
    """ % (mod_name, loaded_api()))
ImportError: 
    Importing PyQt4 disabled by IPython, which has
    already imported an Incompatible QT Binding: pyside
```